# Tab content not hiding jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to create a set of tabs, however, the content isn't hiding when I move tabs it just gets stacked.

Here is my code

HTML

```
<section class="product-features">
    <section class="container">
      <section class="feature-tabs" data-tabgroup="productFeatureTabs">
        <li><a href="#InnovativeStorytelling" class="active">Innovative Storytelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ImmediateEmotionalFeedback">Immediate Emotional Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ExpandingDigitalLibrary">Expanding Digital Library</a></li>
      </section>

      <section class="tab-content" id="productFeatureTabs">
        <!-- start Innovative Storytelling -->
        <section id="InnovativeStorytelling" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Innovative-Storytelling.png" alt="Innovative Storytelling photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/read.svg" alt="Book">
            <h1>Innovative Storytelling</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Innovative Storytelling -->

        <!-- start Immediate Emotional Feedback -->
        <section id="ImmediateEmotionalFeedback" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Immediate-Emotional-Feedback.png" alt="Immediate Emotional Feedback photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/emotion.svg" alt="Emotions">
            <h1>Immediate Emotional Feedback</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Immediate Emotional Feedback-->

        <!-- start Expanding Digital Library -->
        <section id="ExpandingDigitalLibrary" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Expanding-Digital-Library.png" alt="Expanding Digital Library photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/idea.svg" alt="Light Bulb">
            <h1>Expanding Digital Library</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Expanding Digital Library-->
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-content > .tab-panel').hide();
  $('.tab-content > .tab-panel:first-of-type').show();

  $('.feature-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        tabContent = '#'+$this.parents('.tab-content').data('.tab-panel'),
        link = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
        target = $this.attr('href');

    link.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    $(tabContent).children('.tab-panel').hide();
    $(target).show();
  });
});
```

Active is being placed on the tab and the content is showing, however, I can't seem to make the previous tab content to disappear.

So any help or a solution would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to hide the non active contents automatically, and then just toggle the active tab, purely by css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a reference to the current shown panel every time that click function is run, and hide the previous if it exists.

```js
let current = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-content > .tab-panel').hide();
  current = $('.tab-content > .tab-panel:first-of-type').show();
  

  $('.feature-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        tabContent = '#'+$this.parents('.tab-content').data('.tab-panel'),
        link = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
        target = $this.attr('href');
        
    if (current) {
      current.hide();
    }
    
    current = $(target);

    //link.removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');
    $(tabContent).children('.tab-panel').hide();
    $(target).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="product-features">
    <section class="container">
      <section class="feature-tabs" data-tabgroup="productFeatureTabs">
        <li><a href="#InnovativeStorytelling" class="active">Innovative Storytelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ImmediateEmotionalFeedback">Immediate Emotional Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ExpandingDigitalLibrary">Expanding Digital Library</a></li>
      </section>

      <section class="tab-content" id="productFeatureTabs">
        <!-- start Innovative Storytelling -->
        <section id="InnovativeStorytelling" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Innovative-Storytelling.png" alt="Innovative Storytelling photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/read.svg" alt="Book">
            <h1>Innovative Storytelling</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Innovative Storytelling -->

        <!-- start Immediate Emotional Feedback -->
        <section id="ImmediateEmotionalFeedback" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Immediate-Emotional-Feedback.png" alt="Immediate Emotional Feedback photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/emotion.svg" alt="Emotions">
            <h1>Immediate Emotional Feedback</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Immediate Emotional Feedback-->

        <!-- start Expanding Digital Library -->
        <section id="ExpandingDigitalLibrary" class="tab-panel">
          <section class="image">
            <img src="./images/Expanding-Digital-Library.png" alt="Expanding Digital Library photo">
          </section>

          <section class="content">
            <img src="./images/idea.svg" alt="Light Bulb">
            <h1>Expanding Digital Library</h1>
            <p>Hello</p>
          </section>
        </section>
        <!-- end Expanding Digital Library-->
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
```

Comment: You are never really removing the active class from the header anymore, depending on the styling the OP is using, that could be anoying (so my question would be, why did you comment out the link active?)

Comment: OP didn't have a working snippet (no reference to css) so I just coded the important parts. I can change it back though, but I figure OP can tweak that as needed.

Comment: Yeah, this works it looks like I was close, haha, not doing anything special with the CSS so no reason to add it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the .show() when you first start the page, this adds some inline code to the element `display: block;`, which overrides your styling for the panels (i.e. hiding those without `.active`) because inline styles are prioritised over class stylings.

You can simplify your code a little if you would like, I've provided some code below that has the same functionality you are aiming for. This works for any number of tabs on a page, but does not let you have a tab group within another (i.e. as a child). It does require you to add the class `.feature-tabs-wrapper` in a parent div that wraps both the menu links and the panels **(see the third line of the demo HTML below)**.

Let me know if you needed something else.

---

## Demo

```js
// Activate the first panel for any tab setup on the page
$(".feature-tabs-wrapper").each(function() {

  $(this).find(".tab-panel").first().addClass("active");

})


// Add click event to the tab links
$(".feature-tabs > li > a").click(function() {

  // Remove active panel from any of the associated tabs
  $(this).closest(".feature-tabs-wrapper").find(".tab-panel.active").removeClass("active");

  // Get id of tab panel to be activated
  var tabID = $(this).attr("href");
  
  // Activate that tab panel
  $(tabID).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
.tab-panel {
  display: none;
}

.tab-panel.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="product-features">
  
  <section class="container feature-tabs-wrapper">
  
    <section class="feature-tabs" data-tabgroup="productFeatureTabs">
      <li><a href="#InnovativeStorytelling" class="active">Innovative Storytelling</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ImmediateEmotionalFeedback">Immediate Emotional Feedback</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ExpandingDigitalLibrary">Expanding Digital Library</a></li>
    </section>

    <section class="tab-content" id="productFeatureTabs">

      <!-- start Innovative Storytelling -->
      <section id="InnovativeStorytelling" class="tab-panel">
        <section class="image">
          <img src="./images/Innovative-Storytelling.png" alt="Innovative Storytelling photo">
        </section>

        <section class="content">
          <img src="./images/read.svg" alt="Book">
          <h1>Innovative Storytelling</h1>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </section>
      </section>
      <!-- end Innovative Storytelling -->

      <!-- start Immediate Emotional Feedback -->
      <section id="ImmediateEmotionalFeedback" class="tab-panel">
        <section class="image">
          <img src="./images/Immediate-Emotional-Feedback.png" alt="Immediate Emotional Feedback photo">
        </section>

        <section class="content">
          <img src="./images/emotion.svg" alt="Emotions">
          <h1>Immediate Emotional Feedback</h1>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </section>
      </section>
      <!-- end Immediate Emotional Feedback-->

      <!-- start Expanding Digital Library -->
      <section id="ExpandingDigitalLibrary" class="tab-panel">
        <section class="image">
          <img src="./images/Expanding-Digital-Library.png" alt="Expanding Digital Library photo">
        </section>

        <section class="content">
          <img src="./images/idea.svg" alt="Light Bulb">
          <h1>Expanding Digital Library</h1>
          <p>Hello</p>
        </section>
      </section>
      <!-- end Expanding Digital Library-->
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me 
u can try it

code html

```
<section class="product-features">
<section class="container">
    <ul class="feature-tabs" data-tabgroup="productFeatureTabs">
        <li><a href="#InnovativeStorytelling" class="">Innovative Storytelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ImmediateEmotionalFeedback">Immediate Emotional Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ExpandingDigitalLibrary">Expanding Digital Library</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="tab-content" id="productFeatureTabs">
        <!-- start Innovative Storytelling -->
        <section id="InnovativeStorytelling" class="tab-panel active">
           a
        </section>
        <!-- end Innovative Storytelling -->
        <!-- start Immediate Emotional Feedback -->
        <section id="ImmediateEmotionalFeedback" class="tab-panel hidden">
            b
        </section>
        <!-- end Immediate Emotional Feedback-->
        <!-- start Expanding Digital Library -->
        <section id="ExpandingDigitalLibrary" class="tab-panel hidden">
            c
        </section>
        <!-- end Expanding Digital Library-->
    </section>
</section>
```

code jquery

```
(function () {
        var $tabNavigation = $(".feature-tabs a");
        if ($tabNavigation.length > 0) {
            $tabNavigation.on("click", function (e) {
                $('body').find('.feature-tabs li').each(function (index, value) {
                    $(value).removeClass('active');
                })
                $(this).tab("show");

                $('body').find('.tab-panel').each(function (index, value) {
                    if (!$(value).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                    }
                })
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
    })();
```